# UIActionSheet button is not working

Tags: iphone, arrays, uiactionsheet

I have UIActionSheet. It displays the title from array. When i click the button is nothing will happen. I used NSLog also. But it's not displaying anything. Button title is displaying from array. But only click is not working

code:

ActionSheet:

```
TSActionSheet *actionSheet = [[TSActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Design"];

         for (int i = 0; i<[catearray count]; i++ ) {

             [actionSheet addButtonWithTitle:[catearray objectAtIndex:i] block:^{





              }];

         }
```

button click:

```
-(void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    if (buttonIndex == 0) {

        NSLog(@"button");



    } else if (buttonIndex == 1) {

        NSLog(@"button 1");


    } else if (buttonIndex == 2) {


          NSLog(@"button 2");

    } else if (buttonIndex == 3) {

    }





}
```

Array:

```
  if (sqlite3_open([path UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) {

            const char *sql = "SELECT id,cat_name FROM categories";

            NSLog(@"sql is %s",sql);

            sqlite3_stmt *statement;
            //  int catID = 0;
            if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {
                // We "step" through the results - once for each row.
                while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW) {


                    category = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:
                               (const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 1)];
                    NSLog(@"catName is %@",category);

                    [catearray addObject:category];


                    // catID = sqlite3_column_int(statement, 0);
                }
            }


            sqlite3_finalize(statement);
        }

        else {
            sqlite3_close(database);
            NSAssert1(0, @"Failed to open database with message '%s'.", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
            // Additional error handling, as appropriate...
        }
```

Comment: You need to set a delegate to make the delegate methods work.

Comment: How? Im using TSPopoverActionsheet. It's third party. If i use separate button it's working. It i use array it's not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a library called TSActionSheet and actions not called in default UIActionSheetDelegate

so u have to to move your action to a method like this

```
-(void)actionSheetClickedButtonAtIndex:(int)buttonIndex {

     if (buttonIndex == 0) {
        NSLog(@"button");



    } else if (buttonIndex == 1) {

        NSLog(@"button 1");


    } else if (buttonIndex == 2) {


          NSLog(@"button 2");

    } else if (buttonIndex == 3) {

    }
}
```

then call this method on your block like this

```
TSActionSheet *actionSheet = [[TSActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Design"];

         for (int i = 0; i<[catearray count]; i++ ) {

             [actionSheet addButtonWithTitle:[catearray objectAtIndex:i] block:^{

                    [self actionSheetClickedButtonAtIndex:i];



              }];

         }
```

Comment: The [catearray objectAtIndex:i] is coming from webservice. If array is increasing how to set buttonIndex? If i have catearray with 2 buttons. so i use buttonIndex 0,1. After publishing app, then i increase the array in webservice how to set buttonIndex for that updated button

Comment: as long as u're using for loop ... buttons will be set automatically with incremental index ... 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,...,etc. but u have to handle the new buttons functions in actionSheetClickedButtonAtIndex function to make the right action

Comment: Is it possible to incremental index for actionSheetClickedButtonAtIndex like for loop?

Comment: make conditions like in the function until max element u have ... for example write conditions till u reach index ... `else if (buttonIndex == 3) {

    }
    .
    .
    .
else if(buttonIndex == 10){

}else{

}`

Comment: Anyother way to use like for loop for button index instead of if and else if?

Comment: don't think so, but it depends on your situation and your project.

Answer (score 1):

No, you aren't using a UIActionSheet, you're using TSActionSheet which isn't a subclass of UIActionSheet ([It's a subclass of UIView](https://github.com/takashisite/TSPopover/blob/master/TSPopover/TSActionSheet.h)), so there is no expectancy for it to implement the UIActionSheetDelegate protocol. Notice that when you add a button to your TSActionSheet, one of the parameters passed to the button is a block. This is where you place the code you wish to be executed upon button tap.

```
[actionSheet addButtonWithTitle:@"button one" color:[UIColor whiteColor] titleColor:[UIColor darkGrayColor] borderWidth:1 borderColor:[UIColor grayColor] block:^{
        NSLog(@"pushed button one");
}];
```

Comment: The [catearray objectAtIndex:i] is coming from webservice. If array is increasing how to set buttonIndex? If i have catearray with 2 buttons. so i use buttonIndex 0,1. After publishing app, then i increase the array in webservice how to set buttonIndex for that updated button